# Dividing a question along with bounties

Tags: support, bounty

I've asked [a big question with a bounty of 400 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29819/guide-to-particulars-in-customizing-ubuntu-installer). It's not getting the attention and replies as I hoped for. Can I ask for a moderator to break it down to simpler question and dividing the bounty up or canceling it?

Comment: Can you link up the question?

Comment: @Stefano, done. If you do decide to help, please allow me to write the smaller, more focused questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that isn't possible.

If a bounty has been issued, it will be either awarded or lost. It can't be cancelled.

Comment: Regardless, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Oxwivi you should still think about splitting up your question after the bounty period, if you need any help, just let us know

Comment: yep, unfortunately bounty is not possible to divide... i did not know it before ... so it would be a nice feature. Some questions can have more than one solution.